# SAS for CloudBlobDirectory or path within a container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to generate a SAS token or policy for a virtual path within blob container ?

E.g. I have a blob container called `mycontainer`. Inside it have the following blobs

`FolderA/PathA/file.pdf`

`FolderA/PathA/file2.mpg`

`FolderA/PathC/file.doc`

`FolderB/PathA/file.pdf`

I want to generate SAS token such that the client/application can perform operations inside of `FolderA` **only** within container `mycontainer`

Is that possible ?

**Alternate approach is either to**

a) Create a list of SAS tokens for each file (i.e. blockblob) within `FolderA`

b) Re-design such that `FolderA` is a blob container instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to generate SAS token such that the client/application can
>   perform operations inside of FolderA only within container mycontainer
>
> Is that possible ?

No, it is not possible because `Folder` inside a blob container is a virtual entity. Azure  blob storage supports only two level hierarchy - container and blob. A folder is simply the prefix in a blob's name.

Both of the solutions you mentioned below are good alternatives and you would be able to use either of them depending on your use case. My recommendation would be to use approach `(b)` as it provides a nice isolation for individual users in the sense that each user gets her/his own container where they can save their own files.